# Can I use php code inside Big Commerce templates

Tags: php, bigcommerce

Can I use php inside Big Commerce's templates?  Does it need to be inside of a script tag?  What would example "Hello world" code look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[No, you can't.](https://support.bigcommerce.com/?page=support_policy) I hate to make this a link only answer, but there really isn't anything else to say.

Comment: Thats all I needed.  I don't know why BC had to bury that simple fact all the way down there!